# How to report stats with ticker without blocking using channel?

Tags: go, nonblocking

I would like to report various stats every N seconds while reading large file.  I found the ticker and channels but can't figure out how to make it non-blocking while continuing reading the file in the background. I also tried to make string channel and use `select{ case: <-msg}` but the program crashes to deadlock then. What's the proper way?

Later I'll probably add diffs so that speed and time required can be also included in the periodic report.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    filename := "large-file.dat"

    log.Printf("Opening file: '%v'", filename)
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "File error: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    sourceTotalSizeBytes := uint64(0)
    sourceReadedBytes := uint64(0)

    if finfo, err := file.Stat(); err == nil {
        sourceTotalSizeBytes = uint64(finfo.Size())
        log.Printf("Size: %v bytes", sourceTotalSizeBytes)
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    // Output stats every n seconds
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 2)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for scanner.Scan() {
        lineReader := strings.NewReader(scanner.Text())
        sourceReadedBytes += uint64(lineReader.Size())

        // Report stats every n seconds
        <-ticker.C
        go func() {
            percent := ( float64(sourceReadedBytes) * float64(100) ) / float64(sourceTotalSizeBytes)
            log.Printf("%v / %v %v%%", sourceReadedBytes, sourceTotalSizeBytes, percent)
        }()

        // Simulate work being done to line
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10)

    }

    file.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use select with default to avoid blocking on the ticker. Log when a value is received from the ticker:

```
select {
case <-ticker.C:
    percent := ( float64(sourceReadedBytes) * float64(100) ) / float64(sourceTotalSizeBytes)
    og.Printf("%v / %v %v%%", sourceReadedBytes, sourceTotalSizeBytes, percent)
default:
    // do nothing
}
```